# Open a different activity other than MainActivity when clicking Firebase Notification

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-notifications

In my application i want open custom `activity` (not **MainActivity**) and `putExtra` to this `activity` when click on **Firebase** notification.
I write below codes, but when click on notification open **MainActivity**, But i want open my **another activity** (**AuctionDetailActivity**).

**My NotificationManager class :**

```
public class MyNotificationManager {

    private Context mCtx;
    private Uri soundUri;
    private static MyNotificationManager mInstance;

    public MyNotificationManager(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
    }

    public static synchronized MyNotificationManager getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new MyNotificationManager(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public void displayNotification(String title, String body) {

        soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("fcm_notification", "Y");

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mCtx, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mCtx, Constants.NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400})
                .setContentText(body)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) mCtx.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (mNotifyMgr != null) {
            mNotifyMgr.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        }
    }
}
```

**And MyFirebaseMessagingService class :**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        showNotify(remoteMessage.getFrom(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    private void showNotify(String title, String body) {
        MyNotificationManager myNotificationManager = new MyNotificationManager(getApplicationContext());
        //myNotificationManager.displayNotification(title, body);
        myNotificationManager.displayNotification(title, body);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity codes:**

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    String fcm_notification = getIntent().getStringExtra("fcm_notification");
    Log.d("FireBaseIntentLog", " FCM : " + fcm_notification);
    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
            String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);
            Log.d("FireBaseIntentLog", "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value + " FCM : " + fcm_notification);
        }
    }
}
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sending the notification from Firebase console or inside the `notification` field using FCM API, the app behaves in two ways -

- If your app is in foreground, the method `onMessageReceived` of your FCM service class will be called.
- If your app is in background, nothing will happen inside your FCM service class. Rather, the notification will be handled internally by the FCM library itself and the notification with launcher activity in the intent will be shown.

And if you use FCM API to send notification and use the `data` field, the library does nothing itself and instead calls the method `onMessageReceived` regardless of whether your app is in foreground or background.

So in order to solve your issue, you can use one of the following two solutions:

- Use FCM API to send notifications and use the `data` field instead of the `notification` field. Check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/) to read more about FCM API.
- In your launcher (main) activity, check for intent inside `onCreate` and if it is coming from notification, read the extras, finish the main activity and open your required activity.

Example for second case:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (checkIntent()) return;

    // other code.
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    checkIntent();
}

private boolean checkIntent() {
    // to receive the value, send the value as custom data from Firebase console.
    String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("your_key");

    if (value == null) return false;

    if (value.equals("something")) {
        // open one activity.

    } else if (value.equals("another_thing")) {
        // open another activity.
    }

    finish();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro for your help. i updated my above post, please see that. i changed my codes and i want get extra to mainActivity. but when show log `FCM :` show me `null` . how can i fix it? please help me\

Comment: Try checking the extras inside the methods `onCreate` and `onNewIntent`. Also, instead of looping you can simply call `String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("fcm_notification");`

Comment: Can you send to me code with my above codes? please

Comment: Are you here my bro?

Comment: Have you passed the extra value from firebase console? You have accepted the answer. Is your problem solved?

Comment: I send this data in `MyNotificationManager` class with this code : `intent.putExtra("fcm_notification", "Y");` should show me Y in Toast. but show me null !!!!

Comment: please help me. i really need your help . please

Comment: Check answer of your another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52576183/5137352

Answer (score 1):

Change this below line

```
Intent intent = new Intent(click_action);
```

to this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), YourClass.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need modify in `sendNotification` function

```
public void sendNotification(String messageBody, String messageTitle, int user_id, String click_action) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx, AuctionDetailActivity.class); // Need modify this line
    intent.putExtra(Extras.bidID.name(), user_id);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mCtx, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mCtx, Constants.NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your MyFirebaseMessagingService class as shown below replace OtherApp.class with your activity name

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,OtherApp.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);//newbg PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder= new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("FCM NOTIFICATION"); notificationBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());

   }
}
```