# Send data to activity when Firebase notification is clicked in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-intent, android-notifications

In my application I want use **fireBase** for **notification**.
I want when click on notification (when app is closed, my mean is app is `background`) send data with `putExtra` to **mainActivity**.
I write below codes, but when click on **notification** (in app is background) but show me **null** for `getStringExtra` !

**MyNotificationManager class :**

```
public class MyNotificationManager {

    private Context mCtx;
    private Uri soundUri;
    private static MyNotificationManager mInstance;

    public MyNotificationManager(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
    }

    public static synchronized MyNotificationManager getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new MyNotificationManager(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public void displayNotification(String title, String body) {

        soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("fcm_notification", "Y");

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mCtx, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mCtx, Constants.NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400})
                .setContentText(body)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) mCtx.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (mNotifyMgr != null) {
            mNotifyMgr.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        }
    }
}
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService class :**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        showNotify(remoteMessage.getFrom(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    private void showNotify(String title, String body) {
        MyNotificationManager myNotificationManager = new MyNotificationManager(getApplicationContext());
        //myNotificationManager.displayNotification(title, body);
        myNotificationManager.displayNotification(title, body);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity class :**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
if (checkIntent()) return;
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            checkIntent();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

private boolean checkIntent() {
    String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("fcm_notification");
    Toast.makeText(context, "" + value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (value == null) return false;

    if (value.equals("Y")) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LandingActivity.class));
        // open one activity.

    } else if (value.equals("another thing")) {
        // open another activity.
    }

    finish();
    return true;
}
```

When click on notification (on app is background) , show me **null** message in `Toast` for this line `String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("fcm_notification");`

How can i fix it?

Comment: You need to send `data payload` to get data from notification when app is in background.

Comment: @Yupi, can you help me? please send to me code with my above codes. can you help me?

Comment: How do you send notifications? From Firebase Console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending notification from console, add the custom data from 'Advanced options':

[image]

For some reason, firebase doesn't allow the key to start with fcm. You cannot use `fcm_notification`. Use a different key.

For above image, receive the key as follows:

```
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("test_key");
```

Comment: Show me again null :( :(

Comment: please help me, i really need your help my bro. please

Comment: That's odd. Have you added custom data from Firebase console? And have you replaced `fcm_notification` with the key you used?

Comment: If the app is in the background, the code in the method `onMessageReceived` doesn't matter. Notification is created internally by the library. Just add the custom data from FCM console before sending notification.

Comment: I change my codes with new below codes. please see that . in **MyNotificatioManager** = `Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("test_key", keyTest);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mCtx, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);`  ---  In **MyFirebaseMessagingService =** `showNotify(remoteMessage.getFrom(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), remoteMessage.getData().get("test_key"));`  ---  And add `test_key` in custom data on fireBase console. again show me **null** .

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_DATA", title);
```

And to get:

```
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_DATA");
```

Better to change the key. Also, it seems like you'll need to send a data from console and then, sending the data to the another `Activity`.

I've used the current notification `title` to check if it returns the title or not.If it returned the value, so, try sending data from the console.